# LINQ obtaining first item not empty or null from Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have below dictionay:

```
    Dictionary<string, List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>> resp;
    resp = new Dictionary<string, List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>>();
```

And I am trying to obtain the first ErrorMessage from ValidationResult that is not null/empty.

I have create below LINQ expression:

```
    string msg = resp.First(l => l.Value != null).Value.First(vr => vr != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(vr.ErrorMessage)).ErrorMessage;
```

but it raises an Invalid Operation Exception when all the items in the validationResult list for all keys are null and/or empty. It works well when there is at least one validationresult different from null/empty.

Better an image than thousand words so see shared code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cA2ZsG).

Comment: `First` throws this exception if there is no matching element. It seems you are looking for `FirstOrDefault()` instead, which returns `null` instead of throwing.

Comment: @RenéVogt replacing all First by FirstOrDefault returns an exception: [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Comment: @user1624552 try my answer

Comment: @user1624552 That's because all lists are null, so the first `FirstOrDefault()` will return null.

Comment: When using `FirstOrDefault`, you could use the Safe Navigation Operator. So maybe try this: `string msg = resp.First(l => l.Value != null).Value.FirstOrDefault(vr => vr != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(vr.ErrorMessage))?.ErrorMessage;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`First()` throws this exception when there is no matching element in the dictionary. It seems you are looking for `FirstOrDefault()` which returns `null` instead of throwing.

Btw: Your algorithm has a little flaw: If there is a non-null list but it only contains `ErrorMessages` of `null` you don't check the next non-null list.

I suggest to query like that:

```
string msg = resp.Where(x => x.Value != null)
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(vr => vr?.ErrorMessage))
                 .FirstOrDefault(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m));
```

Comment: @tymtam but if you order the items, will orderby respect the order in which items where added? I want to maintain this order.

Comment: my c# compiler version does not recognize ?. This was added on c# 6.0. Could you modify it?

Comment: @user1624552 can these lists even contain a `ValidationResult` that is`null`? If not, you can simply remove the`?`.

Comment: Changing vr?.ErrorMessage by vr == null ? null : vr.ErrorMessage does the same and it works, Thx.